# Fetch image and send it using koa2

Tags: node.js, koa, koa2

I am trying to fetch an image from external URL and then send it as a response in koa2. For fetching the image I am using Axios library.

I am trying to do that the following way:

```
router.get('/get-image', async (ctx, next) => {
    const {authToken} = ctx.query
    const response = await axiosInstance.get(
        'https://www.someurl.com/image/992',
        {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
            },
        }
    )

    ctx.type = 'image/jpeg'
    ctx.body = response.data
})
```

But the image I get from that request is not valid. It only shows empty rectangle).

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to resend the received image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `responseType: 'stream'`. 'arraybuffer' works too, but 'stream' is even better since you're just passing through the bytes.

By default, I believe axios decodes into a utf-8 string which of course is nonsensical for image binary data.

```
const response = await axios.get(url, {
  responseType: 'stream',
  ...
})
```